# HTML5 Canvas not rendering until I change device orientation on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I just decided to come back to an app I worked on a long time ago when Phonegap/Cordova was in it's earlier stages. I'm using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript touch events to draw on the canvas. The plan was to create a real-time drawing game, but now coming back to it with the newer version and a newer Galaxy S4 i seem to be getting some weird behavior. I used a remote mobile debugging tool and can see the touch events being fired but the lines don't show up until i turn my phone sideways or change the device orientation. It works and is drawing the lines correct but not rendering them after the touchend event or touchmove event. I was wondering if anyone has experienced this behavior before? It was working when i developed it a long time ago, i just quit working on the project because I had a phone using Android 2.2 which didn't support DataURIs so I couldn't save the image and had limited functionality. Would love to get this working again. Here is the code.

http://pastebin.com/Q7nWNj0J

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: What is with the down vote? was I not in depth enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the following lines at the end of your events handling functions (at least touchstart and touchmove) :

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

Without that the default Canvas event handling functions are called and the UI is not refreshed.

And if you want to make your app compatible also with android 2, you could use the [Canvas2ImagePlugin plugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) which allows to save a html canvas to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Good question my friend,

137 has a missing semicolon and line 164 has missing semicolon.

Sometimes it's simple thing like that.

Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Nothing, still need to turn the device sideways for lines to show up. it's weird pen size and color work fine but you have to turn the device sideways to render.